# Why won't my element absolutely position?

Tags: css

Working on a CSS3 Menu, but I can't seem to get my `ul` to `position:absolute`.

I'm trying to get the nav element to be in the top left of the screen.

I have used the following code to get this to happen but no changes to the element's positioning take effect.

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

[Codepen link](http://codepen.io/sanjaypoyzer/pen/CHnlw)

Comment: -1, please post some code

Comment: He put a CodePen for us to see, what else are you asking for?

Comment: Sometimes feel like I should have this on a shortcut key, but please read the FAQ, http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: However, I don't understand your question

Comment: @Santz Questions should be self-contained.

Comment: @Liam There is a shortcut! Type this: `[FAQ]` to get this: [FAQ]

Comment: @Santz, questions and answers should not just contain links. This leads to link rot and renders the question useless going forward.

Comment: Cheers @Doorknob, was thinking more of a button that types "Please read the FAQ" :)

Comment: [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: I thought it was pretty self explanatory but fair enough, I have now elaborated the question.

Comment: @Liam not really, actually almost everybody uses JS Fiddles for instance. It's the easyest way to get help and not needing to setup everything by yourself

Comment: @Santz, like John Conde says, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it. These types of questions are discouraged as it limits the usefulness of the resource going forward. SO is trying to be a resource, not just a forum.

Comment: @Santz, also see here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80978/questions-linking-to-external-web-sites-instead-of-showing-code

Comment: you have to style your code

Comment: @Liam Completely understand now why just posting the link and not the code was a bad idea. Sorry. (Although the question was very much based in the link as the answer below proves.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oddly, re-typing the properties/values allows it to work, even though you didn't have any syntax errors

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ICzqx

Comment: Whaaat. That is bizarre. It's actually the second time something really weird like that has happened to me today. What could it be?